# Are Rail Roads required to provide a means of crossing for land-locked (by the RR) private property?

Tags: united-states, real-estate

This is Montana and I'm dealing with MLR (Montana Rail Link) and the tracks are leased from MLR by BNSF (Burlington Northern Santa Fe).

I am a new owner of a property near this RR (Rail-road). Part of our property (a few acres), is only accessible via an existing physical RR crossing. We have been using this crossing, as was the previous owner for farming operations for over 10 years. We have also been letting MDOT (Montana department of transportation) use the crossing to gain access to the creek to pump water for dust control. There is no official record of this crossing other than, it's there physically, MDOT and farmers have been using it. It's not on deeds, and BNSF can't find record of it being permitted. But it is maintained / improved, physical crossing with a passive warning and RR property signage.

Unfortunately MLR 100% unresponsive/unreachable by any means. This has been going on for several months. The question is, do Rail Road companies have some legal obligation placed on them to work with me at all? Are there any laws which require them to work with land holders or can they basically say that I have no access to that part of my property? Is there anything that forces them to allow use of an existing crossing for commerce or private use? Is there an escalation path for me to make them at least communicate with me or are people pretty much at their mercy with this sort of thing?

Of course, I can just keep on using the crossing until told to stop. However, we would like to invest significant money in infrastructure (barns/buildings/storage) on this part of our property. Would hate to be told I can never access it again someday and find out there's nothing I can do.

Comment: @Nij
I guess I would argue that my question is different. My question is asked due to the answer found in the one you linked and it's a different question. I'm being proactive about defining access rights and inquiring if the RR is obligated to work with me. THe question you linked is regarding a reaction to someone who was trespassing without asking permission. But, they are very similar!

Answer (score -1):

#### You have an easement on the crossing regardless of what they want.

Common passage has been established.  They know this and are working on other things.  The chance of them coming after you are approximately zero as long as you don't walk along the tracks.

If you are concerned about how solid your easement would be in court, you need a local lawyer.

Comment: Is this similar to a "Contract Implied in Fact" scenario? Like... an Easement can be "Implied in Fact"?

Comment: @maplemale, it isn't a contract, it is the right to enter real property but not to use it.  Like if the neighborhood kids have used your yard for a generation to walk to school, you won't be able to put up a fence.

Comment: [This story](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/72638/can-a-railroad-bar-a-property-owner-from-access-to-their-property) apparently had probability zero, by your estimation, but it happened.

Comment: @NateEldredge This is my concern. And TY for the question link btw! I think my question is more, out of concern for situations you lined out. It seems the RR DOES indeed have the ability to restrict access to other's properties. Which, is the reason for my question. It's 100% possible and has happened. So, before I invest a large amount of money on infrastructure i'm not just going to gamble on a probability.

Comment: @NateEldredge that case is quite different as it involves a hunter (presumably on foot) crossing where there is no obvious and maintained crossing point. However, I don’t think the case is as clear cut as Tiger Guy suggests.

Comment: Railroads are *not* ordinary property, where an easement can be established by custom. They are often enough so special, that even *the state needs to acquire a special permit from the operator to do basic stuff like fixing a road on a crossing* because it *could* impact train traffic.